# Would blocking an entire ip range of a country potentially hinder performance?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip

We've discovered a lot of brute-force attack attempts on our server originating from a particular country. We plan to block all incoming traffic from that country, but it is [quite a list](http://pastebin.com/qFmGY629). To be safe, we're also going to be blocking some other nations as well where we don't plan to provide our web services to.

Would adding such a large list to the firewall rule hinder network performance in any conceivable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on where you will be blocking it.

If you will be blocking it at your server then you will still experience the connection attempts through your internet connection as well as the ICMP connection refused packets going out.

If you block them at your router, you will still have both sets of packets impacting your internet connection.  (they could still potentially DOS you)

If you ask your ISP to block them then you are unlikely to experience any negative effects (so long as your ISP has enough bandwidth to survive said potential DOS attack).

One other thing to check before you block that large range:
Make sure none of the root DNS servers are located in that range, otherwise you could set yourself up for some long waits randomly popping up on DNS requests.

Answer (score 2):

Blocking a large range of ip addresses is always have consequences on servers,its really depend upon that how long is your block list and your hardware/software specifications. A hardware is good alternative for it but its costly solution,so its better that isp provider is requested to block the ip addresses. That save you from lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your router, however I've configured way more complex access lists on an old Linux box without any issues.  What spec hardware are you using, and how hard are you pushing it?

I'd also point out (as an amusing aside) to you that the country you appear to be filtering[ China ] does its own blocking on a massive scale, probably an inverse match !!